# Why is there a so-called identity conversion?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

If an identity conversion does not do anything (whenever I have encountered it in the standard, it was simply to tell that there was no need for conversion), why is it a thing? What is its true purpose?

Exmaples of its usage

From the standard (n3690 13.3.3.1.1):

> As described in Clause 4, a standard conversion sequence is either the
>   Identity conversion by itself (that is, no conversion) or consists of
>   one to three conversions from the other four categories.

13.3.3.1:

> If no conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter
>   type, the implicit conversion sequence is the standard conversion
>   sequence consisting of the identity conversion

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization):

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is an aggregate which can be
>   initialized from the initializer list according by aggregate
>   initialization, the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined
>   conversion sequence with the second standard conversion sequence an
>   identity conversion.

```
struct A { int m1; double m2;};
void f(A);
f({'a','b'});  // calls f(A(int,double)), user-defined conversion
```

"with the second standard conversion sequence an identity conversion" - is that even worth mentioning?

Comment: I would guess that it's just a way in standardese to specify conversions unambiguously. It would help if you quoted where identity conversion is mentioned in the standard.

Comment: It makes it possible to reason about conversions in a general way and without always adding "or no conversion" as a special case in every other sentence.

Comment: Identities are important and need formalizing. This is exactly like how you would set up axioms in maths: `∀x : 0 + x =  x + 0 = x`

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the identity conversion is to act as a base case and allow us to reason about conversions without having to single out the case where no conversion is needed.

Comment: So in the cppreference article that I linked, how can it be worth stating that "with the second standard conversion sequence an identity conversion"? If they did not write that, I would have assumed that the first AND the second standard conversion were not required anyway...

Comment: @FacPam A user defined conversion sequence is defined by an intial standard conversion sequence followed by a user defined conversion followed by a second standard conversion sequence. Saying that the second standard conversion sequence is a is an identity conversion is the same as saying that the user defined conversion must be the last conversion in the chain.

Comment: @FacPam The first standard conversion may be not identity.

Comment: Thank you Johan! @xskxzr could you provide an example in which the first standard conversion in a user-defined conversion is NOT an identity conversion then? That would be cool!

Comment: Or in fact, anyone with a kind soul is allowed to show me an example of this if they can find one :))

Comment: @FacPam No I can't, in a language-lawyer manner, because the standard does not specify what the first standard conversion is (no matter what it is, the observable result is consistent, as the first standard conversion sequence has no effect on ranking user-defined conversion sequences).